# Programmatically delete files from blob storage after x number of days

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-blob-storage-delete

I want to delete files from Azure Blob Storage after X number of days automatically. I don't want to create a Azure function for this. I want to do this programmatically and not through policy.

At the time of uploading the file, I want to set a rule/policy programmatically instructing to delete the files after X number of days.

I also tried setting meta data ([RetensionDays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75818517/is-there-a-way-to-set-metadata-on-a-blob-at-the-time-of-creation-using-current-a)) but it did not helped.

Comment: You don't want to use Lifecycle Management Policies - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-lifecycle-management-concepts?

Comment: @GauravMantri: Are you asking me why I don't want to use the policies?  or suggesting that i should look into policies ?

Comment: he's suggesting you should use policies which will do this for you automatically